# preg_match with excluding comma and point

Tags: php, preg-match

```
if (!preg_match('/[^a-z ćčžđš\0-9]/i', $_POST['a'])) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

I use this for allowing only alphanumeric characters plus specific local characters for croatian language.

It works but it also allows comma, point... and maybe something else.
How to exclude any other characters except a-z, my local characters, spaces and numbers?

for example - should not be allowed:

- abc,
- abc.
- abc+

...
and should be allowed:

- abc

Comment: "It works but it also allows comma, point... and maybe something else"... Maybe? You haven't tried your code? Also your question does not match the previous text. You write; " use this for allowing only alphanumeric characters plus specific local characters for croatian language" but then your question is [a-z0-9]

Comment: @Andreas - when I saw it allows commas and points - didn't check the rest.

Comment: Why do you have backslash before `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code:

1) To check if your string contains forbidden characters and display the error message, you use a double negation:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^allowed characters]/i', ...
#   ^--------------^
```

This means *"if the string doesn't contain a forbidden character, then display 'error'"*.

In my opinion the correct algorithm is more:

```
if ( preg_match('/[^allowed characters]/i', ...
```

2) If you escape the 0 in 0-9 inside a character class, you define a range between the null character and the character 9 *(see the ascii table)*

3) You are dealing with unicode characters, you have to use the u modifier, otherwise the regex engine will read your string byte by byte and return false positive:

```
if ( preg_match('/[^a-z ćčžđš0-9]/iu', $_POST['a']) )
    echo 'error!';
```

To finish, accented characters can be written in two ways in unicode for example `č` can be:

- the single codepoint U+010D   (LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON)
- the combination of the codepoint U+0063   (LATIN SMALL LETTER C) and the codepoint U+030C (COMBINING CARON)

Your pattern will not handle the second case. To avoid the problem, you have to normalize your string first with the [intl normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php).

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the backslash before "0-9" in your regexp.
You have double negation, and you can add the "^" for start and "$" for end. 
The
 Unicode chars need "u" modifier

I have change your code like this :

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z ćčžđš0-9]*$/iu', $_POST['a'])) {
   echo 'ok';
} else {
   echo 'error';
}
```

I suggest you to test your regexp with a online regex tester (for example https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I remove the backslash, but comma and points are still allowed

Comment: I have changed my answer by removing negation, adding "^" and "$"

Comment: I tried and now my local characters are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Having the backslash before `0-9` makes it a character group in the range between character 0 and number 9 (index 0 and 57, respectively), not number 0 and number 9. A comma (44) and a point (46) are coincidentally inside that range, so it doesn't work as you need it to.

To make it work, remove the slash:

```
[^a-z ćčžđš0-9]
```

Comment: I remove the backslash, but comma and points are still allowed

Comment: Can you provide an example of a string that *should* and a string that *shouldn't* pass your condition?